# What should I be thinking about when securing copper pipe to a cinder block wall?

Tags: mounting, copper-pipe

I am an amateur but have had to do a lot of maintenance on my (very low-income) parents' old kit house in the past few years, and can do most simple jobs with the right instruction.

In their basement there is a cinder block wall against which copper water pipes have been hanging forever. These pipes serve the clothes washing machine, as well as being connected to a long-disused sink. For as long as I can remember, the pipes have been essentially hanging loose, supported by a combination of hanger ties and resting on other stronger pipes, and have always shook when the washer cycle gets going. Over the years they've bent *very slightly*, and I'm paranoid that one day they're going to shake so hard that they crack, flooding the basement. I want to replace the pipes as a gift to my parents, but that's going to have to wait until next year. In the short term, I want to guard as best I can against the possibility that they could burst under normal use.

My thinking was one of two things:

- masonry bit into the cinder blocks, hang lead anchors, secure pipes with hanger straps screwed into anchors
- masonry bit into the cinder blocks, hang lead anchors, screw a 2"x4"x2" piece of wood into the wall and mount the pipe on the wood with a pipe strap

thoughts? thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If they run close to the wall these are classic. Probably not the low-cost leader, though.

[image: Copper pipe standoff]

*image source https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fi5.walmartimages.com%2Fasr%2Fa79eb849-0af8-4f76-9a7b-fda9f4d6c843_1.e9592268f1daf2da4703cd03dc0abfa2.jpeg%3FodnWidth%3D1000%26odnHeight%3D1000%26odnBg%3Dffffff&f=1&nofb=1&ipt=a3df2b902a56317fd94e79d142defabf373b2736a453469080bc55fe796cc8cc&ipo=images no endorsement impled*

In any case, you want to be wary of setting up galvanic corrosion. So don't make the copper pipe touch the cinderblock wall directly, and if you choose hangers like this, either do mount wood to screw them in to, or at least put plastic between them and the cinderblock. Iron pipe strap, despite being galvanized, can  be an issue with copper pipes long-term. Plastic supports, despite an element of cheesy appearance, don't rot out the pipes.

If you happen to know anyone doing a "modern materials" deck, Trex or similar plastic-wood scraps are excellent for masonry-mount boards that won't rot out. I guess PVC trim lumber could also work.

Comment: thank you so much for the advice